# Executing DDL "Alter table user_roles drop foreign key" Error in Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

```
2024-01-31T14:44:44.631+03:00  WARN 22160 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table user_roles drop foreign key FKe9wywyhbehk4sruldi99vh9g7" via JDBC [Table 'mangaweb.user_roles' doesn't exist]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table user_roles drop foreign key FKe9wywyhbehk4sruldi99vh9g7" via JDBC [Table 'mangaweb.user_roles' doesn't exist]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:470) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropConstraintsTablesSequences(SchemaDropperImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
```

I think it gives this error because can't drop that foreign key FKe9wywyhbehk4sruldi99vh9g7 from that table. Probably because while create-drop it runs that code before create.

I really didn't understand why im getting that error

Answer (score 0):

> via JDBC **[Table 'mangaweb.user_roles' doesn't exist]**

Well it can't bre dropped because the table itself doens't exist, you should check the orders of your scripts, maybe the order of the script altering the table user_roles is being executed before the creation of the table itself

Comment: It's exists but it says that still

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you are connecting to another DB, check your profile at your IDE and check the propreties of your project to check if you are poiting to the rigth datasource, denpending on your profile your project can be set to point to diferents datasource

Comment: I tried it and im on right datasource. I also have that tables and pulling data from them im using them. It's just giving that errors and not refreshing old foreign keys. Without it my codes are still working but that's weird and i don't know what to do